# Access nested List elements and convert into List<String[]>

Tags: list, csv, spring-mvc, export-to-csv, opencsv

I developed csv download functionality in Spring MVC using OpenCSV library, the data required to be written on file is holding by below DTO class

```
public class CsvDataDto {

    private String fileName;
    List<String> header=new ArrayList<>();;
    private String heading;
    List<List<Object>> data=new ArrayList<>();
//getters and setters

}
```

I want flexible and dynamic functionality, so that, I initialized the data of `CsvDataDto` in my controller method `downloadFile()`

```
// Download Method snippet
if (type.equals("csv")) {
            CsvDataDto dataDTO = new CsvDataDto();
            dataDTO.setFileName("Table_Data");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("User Id");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("First Name");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("Last Name");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("Roll No");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("Email ID");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("Gender");
            List<UserInfo> list = userInfoDao.findById(tableId);
            for (UserInfo infoList : list) {
                List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                newList.add(infoList.getUserId());
                newList.add(infoList.getFirstName());
                newList.add(infoList.getLastName());
                newList.add(infoList.getRollNo());
                newList.add(infoList.getEmail());
                newList.add(infoList.getGender());
                dataDTO.getData().add(newList);

            }
```

Till here everything is fine , the moment where I stuck is to access the elements inside `List<List<Object>>`, which would be added in above snippet, and also then convert the same into `List<String[]>`, because, `write()` method Of `CsvWriter` takes either `String[]` or `List<String[]>` as an argument.

The Final Snippet where data will be write into the file.

```
List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<>();
        String csvFileName = csvDataDto.getFileName();
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvFileName));

        String[] headerArr = new String[csvDataDto.getHeader().size()];
        headerArr = csvDataDto.getHeader().toArray(headerArr);
        records.add(headerArr);

        for (List<Object> objList : csvDataDto.getData()) {
            System.out.println("object list:" + objList);
            String[] fileData = new String[objList.size()];
            fileData = objList.toArray(fileData);
            records.add(fileData);
        }
        writer.writeAll(records);
        writer.close();
```

The above logic need to be improved, because my downloaded file is blank.
When I debug the `List<List<Object>>`. I can see the 7 different List, but when I want to loop over that inner list to access data, so JVM didn't let me do this because of type `Object`.

**CASE for `List<List<Object>>`**

I knew that there is collection of `list<Object>` inside `List`, the main data stored in each inner list, I want to fetch each list what I tried, i mentioned below, but still i am not succeeded

```
for(List<Object> objList : csvDataDto.getData())
{
for(UserInfo info:(UserInfo)objList ){ // NOT ALLOWED CHANGE TYPE TO Object
}
}
```

If i do this, then i am not able to fetch the records like `getId()`, `getName()`,`getRollNo()`

```
 for(List<Object> objList : csvDataDto.getData())
    {
    for(Object obj:objList ){ // I didn't found any of my getter, just found all mthod of Object class itself

    }
    }
```

**Similar Case for `List<String> header`**

I need to add `String[]` in  `List<String[]> records`, so its necessary for me to fetch all the elements from `List<String> header` and then convert it into String[] and add the same in `records`. I tried this but no luck

```
String[] headerArr = new String[csvDataDto.getHeader().size()];
        headerArr = csvDataDto.getHeader().toArray(headerArr);
        records.add(headerArr);
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**
1. My Csv file having headers so, i need to iterate the `List<String[]>` header, add the data into `records.add()`, and pass the same to `write()`.

2.The actual data which is inside `List<List<Object>>`, I need to iterate the elements inside and convert them into `String[]` and add the data into `records.add()`, and pass the same to `write()`.

```
userid, fname,lastname,rollno,gender 

1     , john,   doe   ,1001,   M     
2     , Rose,   Mary  ,1002,   F
3     , Jack,   Jill  ,1003,   M
```

Comment: Have you tried to use flatMap? if no check : https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-flatmap-example/

Comment: can u demonstrate the same by using my scenario

Comment: Is CsvDataDto defined by you? can you modify that class or it is from some API?

Comment: CsvDataDao is my custom DTO class

Comment: Why don't you use Generics instead of object? something like CsvDataDao<Foo> so you can access Foo methods instead of having to cast obejects

Comment: can you please demonstrate the same, it will be easy and useful for me

Comment: Am i using the bad approach ??

Comment: I will try to explain it in the answer, let s see if we can improve this to make your task easier :)

Comment: ok OEH, thanks in advance

Comment: If u can post some snippet by implementing your suggestion over my scenario, then it will be very useful for all of us, my primary focus is to fetch the elements from List<List<Object>> and convert the Same to String[], now I welcoming your suggestions to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can facilitate your task via making some changes on CsvDataDto

you can do something like this

```
public class CsvDataDto<T> {

    private String fileName;
    List<String> header=new ArrayList<>();
    private String heading;
    List<List<T>> data=new ArrayList<>();
//getters and setters

}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to deal with Objects and Casting which can leads to errors.

Anywhere you will have to loop for example when you mentioned:

```
for(List<Object> objList : csvDataDto.getData())
    {
    for(Object obj:objList ){ // I didn't found any of my getter, just found all mthod of Object class itself

    }
    }
```

you instead  will have

```
for(List<FooClass> objList : csvDataDto<FooClass>.getData())
    {
    for(FooClass obj:objList ){ 
       ... //here you can access the methods of FooClass, 
    }
    }
```

Changing your DTO design can make your task easier.

FooClass stands for a class of your choice, so can be anything, probably in your case it will be `UserInfo`.

So when you do this in your first step:

```
    // Download Method snippet
if (type.equals("csv")) {
            CsvDataDto dataDTO = new CsvDataDto();
            dataDTO.setFileName("Table_Data");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("User Id");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("First Name");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("Last Name");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("Roll No");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("Email ID");
            dataDTO.getHeader().add("Gender");
            List<UserInfo> list = userInfoDao.findById(tableId);
            for (UserInfo infoList : list) {
                List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                newList.add(infoList.getUserId());
                newList.add(infoList.getFirstName());
                newList.add(infoList.getLastName());
                newList.add(infoList.getRollNo());
                newList.add(infoList.getEmail());
                newList.add(infoList.getGender());
                dataDTO.getData().add(newList);

            }
```

you can replace `List<Object>` with `List<UserInfo>` and add the list in `CsvDataDTO<UserInfo>` without any problem. 
So later on you can retrieve it as I mentioned above in the example

Comment: hmm I think that make sense, but i raise a case for List<String>header, I iterate the same and convert the same into String[], but still, data didn't wrote in my csv file, how would that happened

Comment: I understand, unfortunately would need to debug the code and be there in order to be more useful.

Comment: However, this is still not universal, because every time i need to change the code for different objects, can you suggest me the way to make that method work for any type

Comment: Working with Generics is the correct choice, not with Object. Please refer to the benefit of generics. However in here we have to understand first why you file is blank. when you do writer.writeAll(records); can you debug and see that records it is actually full of the infos?

Comment: The purpose for writing download method like this is simply to make the download functionality universal,